# GUI design for color blindness

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, color-scheme, color-blindness

It is common to represent status of an item in a GUI using the colors: red, yellow, green, to mean error, warning, and OK (or something equivalent). However, 7-10% of men have difficulty distinguishing between red and green because of [color blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Red-green_color_blindness).

So far I've looked at [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) which simulates how people with different color blindnesses would perceive a set of colors, but I'm interested in hearing how you have approached this problem and how successful it was.

Comment: Just to note that "red-green colour blindness" does not necessarily mean a complete inability to tell red from green. I have some trouble distinguishing some deep greens from brown, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an interesting piece on [designing for color-blindness](http://www.stcsig.org/usability/newsletter/9910-color-blindness.html).

One of the task-aways is never to rely solely on color.  Always have some other indicator (text, icons) for a particular task.

Comment: An example other than icons is the common usage to use bold typeface for unread messages in mail applications.

Comment: I found comments in the "designing for color-blindness" interesting beyond the advice for using symbols.

Answer (score 9):

Don't depend on the colours. You could apply symbols too (e.g. green tick, yellow triangle, red hexagon) or use text labels.

Comment: This is what we do.  We have scores for projects that can be green (circle), yellow (square), or red (triangle).

Answer (score 1):

Use 'common' symbolic icons as well as colour to represent statuses.

Might be useful: [Where can one find free software icons / images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images)

Answer (score 1):

Many UI designers start with black-and-white designs, and later add color to accent or emphasize, but only after the black-and-white design meets all the design goals.

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive the necroposting, but if you absolutely must use color, I've found colorbrewer2.org very helpful - it has some nice pre-generated color palettes that they classify as "colorblind safe." Of course, as has been posted, avoid color when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Get any book about "accessibility" and you should have plenty of suggestions. They will more or less boil down to a simple principle: do not bind any information to color solely. That is, color should just be accompanying the information, which should never be conveyed by color only.
I used Linux to develop one such application, and I used Compiz filters to simulate color blindness: very handy.
As a side note, there are more types of color blindness out there, so pay attention to that too.

Answer (score 0):

The company I worked for hired a colour-blind Swing developer - me!

Comment: That doesn't help much as there are many different types and degrees of colour blindness.

Answer (score 0):

Don't employ colour-blind operatives. ( Apparently the discrimination laws in the non-EU country we were selling the software in allowed this; YMMV )